# Prevent click on transparent part of image on pictureBox windows form

Tags: c#, click, picturebox

I have a `picturebox` and an `image` on it (icon image) with transparent parts and a `logo` at the middle of it. I want to activate the `click` event of this `picturebox` only when the user clicks the logo and prevent it for the rest of the transparent parts of the `picturebox`.

Comment: i'm only asking about the way to make button using a picturebox but prevent the click event at the transparent part .
like the mhk shaped button tool search for it to understand more .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it a button 
-First create the picture box and size your image as you see fit
-Create a transparent label over the picture box to cover your image and make it clickable so it would appear as if the image is clicked
That should work

Comment: good idea i think it will work i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Scale the picture and the picture box so it wouldn't display the transparent part of the image

Comment: i tried this but the shape i want to use is circular so there will be a transparent part anyway